# Comparing Agent Jobs on Two Servers

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm currently building a process in `Powershell` where we can copy `SQL Server Agent` jobs from one server to another server just by entering the server names.  The script uses the SMO library to obtain access to both job servers, scripts the jobs that don't exist on the "other" server, then runs those scripts (under a SqlConnection and SqlCommand).  The issue is how to check if a job exists on `ServerOne` compared to `ServerTwo`.

I've tried four different approaches: build an array with the jobs from ServerTwo (the compare server) and see if that array `contains` a job from ServerOne; I also tried the like operator with the same logic; and, using arrays, I've used `Compare-Object` after loading two arrays with job names from both servers and measuring which jobs don't exist in the other (produces everything too).  Finally, I looped through each job on ServerTwo and looped through each job on ServerOne to see if they equal each other (which is the below code).  This will produce everything because each job doesn't equal each job:

```
$ServerName = "S1\I"
$ComServer = "S2\I"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null
$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $ServerName
$com = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $ComServer


foreach ($a in $com.JobServer.Jobs)
{
    $a = $a.Name.ToString() 
    foreach ($j in $srv.JobServer.Jobs) 
    { 
        $j = $j.Name.ToString()

        if ($a -like $j)
        {
            Write-Host $j
        }
    }   
}
```

Is there another approach to this where I can check if a job exists on one server vs. another (as a note, I already know how to script the job, execute it and so on; the part of making sure the job doesn't already exist is the problem here)?

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of comparing job name to job name?

Comment: @billinkc Yeah, that's what I tried to do with `Compare-Object`, but it produced all jobs, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see from the comments that you've already given `Compare-Object` a try, but that really should be working.  Below is a working example showing this:

```
$SqlServer1Name = "SQL1"
$SqlServer2Name = "SQL2"

$SqlServer1 = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($SqlServer1Name)
$SqlServer2 = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($SqlServer2Name)

$SqlServer1JobListing = $SqlServer1.JobServer.Jobs | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$SqlServer2JobListing = $SqlServer2.JobServer.Jobs |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

Compare-Object $SqlServer1JobListing $SqlServer2JobListing |
    Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

This will output all of the jobs that live on `SQL1` and *not* on `SQL2`.  This comparison is by name only, not taking into consideration any other SQL Server Agent Job attributes.